# Why am I getting Jupyter Notebook validation failed messages that read like spam emails?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have been using a jupyter notebook to explore some output files I created and compare performance. Nothing fancy - mostly just using pandas to clean, read, and write. Today, seemingly out of the blue, this particular notebook raises a "Notebook validation failed" error. Here is the text in the error:

```
"Notebook validation failed: Non-unique cell id 'irish-profile' detected. Corrected to 'sexual- 
vitamin'.:
"<UNKNOWN>""
```

The language changes from message to message. Earlier the message had a non-unique cell of 'solid-congress' and changed it to 'happy-america'. Any idea what this is - am I hacked?

Answer (score 0):

You can test this :

Select all the cells in the Jupyter Notebook, then press the "cut/scissors" button, and finally press the "paste" button.